# Does my Neural Net Vector Input Size Need to Match the Output Size?

Tags: neural-network, data-science

I’m trying to use a Neural Network for purposes of binary classification. It consist of three layers. The first layer has three input neurons, the hidden layer has two neurons, and the output layer has three neurons that output a binary value of 1 or 0. Actually the output is usually a floating point number, but it typically rounds up to a whole number.

If the network only outputs vectors of 3, then shouldn't my input vectors be the same size? Otherwise, for classification, how else do you map the output to the input?

I wrote the neural network in Excel using VBA based on the following article: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/05/neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-and-r/
So far it works exactly as described in the article. I don’t have access to a machine learning library at the moment so I’ve chosen to give this a try.

For example:

If the output of the network is [n, n ,n], does that mean that my input data has to be [n, n, n] also?

From what I read in here: [Neural net input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205449/neural-net-input-output)

It seems that's the way it should be. I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: I think you have a big misconception, inputs and outputs to the neural network don't have to be of the same size, for example, to classify a 32x32 image into 10 classes, you have an input of 32x32, and an output of 10 elements.

Comment: So, if you have an input of 32x32, and an output of 10 elements, how do map the output to the input? I guess that's what I don't understand. It seems if the output isn't the same size as your input vectors, you wouldn't be able to classify.

Comment: What do you mean map the output to the input? The usual neural networks map an input to the output.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, that networks internally map input to output. Externally though, what I don't understand is this; In my particular case, the network outputs a vector of 1 x 3. I don't know what that means? How would that tell me which class it's predicting?

Comment: Well you have to design your network to fit your data, including the dimensions of the input and output, so for me a 1x3 vector means nothing, because I don't know what data you plan to use for training, you mention binary classification, but that is not done with 3 output neurons. Details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

To speak simple,
for regression task, your output usually has the dimension `[1]` (if you predict single value).

For the classification task, your output should have the same number of dimensions equal to the number of classes you have (outputs are probabilities, the sum of them = 1).

So, there is no need to have equal dimensions of input and output. NN is just a projection of one dimension to another.

For example,

- regression, we predict house prices: input is `[1, 10]` (to features of the property), the output is `[1]` - price
- classification, we predict class (will be sold or not): input is `[1, 11]` (same features + listed price), output is `[1, 2]` (probability of class `0` (will be not sold) and `1` (will be sold); for example, `[1; 0]`, `[0; 1]` or `[0.5; 0.5]` and so on; it is binary classification)

Additionally, equality of input-output dimensions exists in more specific tasks, for example, autoencoder models (when you need to present your data in other dimension and then represent it back, to the original dimension).

Again, the output dimension is the size of outputs for 1 batch. Only one, not of the whole dataset.